# How to get the previous month name of a given month in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have column `A` starting form `A1` with french month names :

```
FEVRIER
AOUT
DECEMBRE
JANVIER
```

How to get the previous month name and put it in the column `B` starting from `B1` ?

```
JANVIER
JUILLET
NOVEMBRE
#NA
```

Can you guys show me how to do that using an Excel formula ? I'm using 365 on Sharepoint.

Comment: Try: `=LET(x, (MONTH(A1&1)-1)*29, TEXT(IF(x=0,NA(),x),"mmmm"))`

Comment: You're awesome. Can you add it as an answer please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following `Excel Formula`:

[image]

---

```
=LET(x, (MONTH(A1:A4&1)-1)*29, UPPER(TEXT(IF(x=0,NA(),x),"mmmm")))
```

---

In `French Excel` it would be

```
=LET(x;(MOIS(A1:A4&1)-1)*29;MAJUSCULE(TEXTE(SI(x=0;NA();x);"mmmm")))
```

---

Bit shorter method:

[image]

---

```
=IFERROR(UPPER(TEXT((A1:A4&"-1900")-29,"mmmm")),NA())
```

---

• In `French`

```
=SIERREUR(MAJUSCULE(TEXTE((A1:A4&"-1900")-29;"mmmm"));NA())
```

---

Comment: `=if(x=0,348,x)` for December?

Comment: @P.b Sir OP wants if its January then the previous month will be `#N/A` as far i have understood

Comment: Oh, I see in the example

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [`EDATE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/edate-function-3c920eb2-6e66-44e7-a1f5-753ae47ee4f5) (or [`EOMONTH`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/eomonth-function-7314ffa1-2bc9-4005-9d66-f49db127d628)) function.

```cpp
=IF(A1:A12="January",NA(),TEXT(EDATE(1&A1:A12,-1),"mmmm"))
```

[image]